# Testing Rails app with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In testing my rails app (using RSpec and Capybara) I am having troubles testing AngularJS functions (from the Users point of view). Can I not test with only RSpec and Capybara or do I also need something like protractor?

any help would be great! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test with Capybara, so long as you use a driver that supports javascript, such as Selenium or Poltergeist - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

However, although I'm not an AngularJS user, I do know that it's designed to be testable, and I imagine you'd be much better off using a tool specifically for javascript testing, rather than capybara.

Answer (score 0):

As long as angular provides it's own methods and functionalities you should separate the testing suite into two. The first one, rspec, capybara and rails will be testing just the non-angular pages.

Second one, using a tool like jasmine should be testing the angular behaviour. Both combined provides good coverage of the application.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing